# Page hangs on multi command mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm mostly just struggling my way through it but I've hit a roadblock that I just can't get over.

My goal is to run a few commands to clear and update a standings table and then display the data in a table. I've got the table to display pretty much no problem but when I add the code in to update the table the page stops before it even displays the table and it's just a blank page, it wont even run any of the HTML.

Here's the PHP, I can provide the rest of the page code if needed.

http://pastebin.com/GZ3KcNXK

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","uakronhv_admin","uakhvzdbadmin01","uakronhv_game1");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
    $sql = "DELETE FROM standings WHERE 1=1; ";
    $sql. = "INSERT INTO standings (`pId`,`pName`,`pStarve`) SELECT p.pId, concat(p.pFirst," ",p.pLast), TIMEDIFF(NOW(),s.lastTag) FROM players p left join starve s on p.pId = s.zId; ";
    $sql.= $mysqli_real_escape_string("UPDATE standings SET sStatus = "Human" WHERE sId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggedId FROM tags); "):
    $sql.= $mysqli_real_escape_string("UPDATE standings SET sStatus = "Zombie" WHERE (sId IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggedId FROM tags)) OR (sId IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggerId FROM tags)); "):    

    $que=$mysqli_query($sql);

    $sp = mysqli_query($con,"call updateStandings()");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM standings");

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Since Last Tag</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" . $row['pId'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" . $row['pStatus'] . "</td>";
        if ($row['pStarve'] > '72:00:00')
            echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\">Starved</td>";
        else if
            (is_null($row['pStarve']))
            echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\">--</td>";
        else
            echo "<td >" . $row['pStarve'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Where's the code? I don't see any here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (And no, I'm not following your link)

Comment: `$sql = "DELETE FROM standings WHERE 1=1; ";` I'm not sure what that's going to do.

Comment: Do paste code instead of a pastebin. *You're welcome*.

Comment: Use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` since you're not checking for errors. Plus, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This is some pretty unruly `mysqli` code. Where did you learn to do it this way? Escaping entire subqueries is not going to work at all. When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Calling the escape functions manually should be done only as a last resort.

Comment: Plus this `$mysqli_real_escape_string` - *cough* and `$mysqli_query` *cough* - don't ask yourself why your page hangs. Whoever makes this code work, deserves the Golden Vote award.

Comment: Like I said, new to PHP and struggling through. I really don't know what/how I should or should not be doing. I've been looking around the internet and a lot of places seem to do things differently.
As for the DELETE line, I just want to clear the table. I realize there are probably better ways, but it works and I know that's not where the issue is.
Can you guys suggest either a) the best way to do what I'm trying to accomplish or b) a good place to learn?

Comment: Also this page has no input, it is simply being called to show the standings table, so I don't think I could run into sql injection here. Possibly on other pages but I'll deal with that later. I really just need to be able to run these commands at the moment.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, starting on a foundation provided by a
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) such as [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is considerably better than grinding away at low-level PHP and making a mess of things. Frameworks provide examples of best practices, lots of support for routine things, and a whole lot of community code you can leverage when solving problems and building your application. The kind of code you've demonstrated here is a stew of SQL, HTML and CSS and is extremely hard to maintain.

Comment: I think what people are trying to say is that you need to step back and figure out the basics before you continue with what you're doing. Your code demonstrates ignorance of the difference between variables and functions. This is a warning flag that you're in over your head. Nobody here will give you much advice on how to learn this stuff, but once you've figured some things out you can always come back and ask for help with specific coding problems. Good luck!

Comment: @tylerkenepp I have outlined the errors in your code with an answer below. Please go over it very carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to point out where the faults are, which may very well fix your code. If it doesn't, then you will need to read up on the better tutorials.

**Regarding this code block:**

```
$sql. = "INSERT INTO standings (`pId`,`pName`,`pStarve`) SELECT p.pId, concat(p.pFirst," ",p.pLast), TIMEDIFF(NOW(),s.lastTag) FROM players p left join starve s on p.pId = s.zId; ";
$sql.= $mysqli_real_escape_string("UPDATE standings SET sStatus = "Human" WHERE sId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggedId FROM tags); "):
$sql.= $mysqli_real_escape_string("UPDATE standings SET sStatus = "Zombie" WHERE (sId IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggedId FROM tags)) OR (sId IN (SELECT DISTINCT taggerId FROM tags)); "):    

$que=$mysqli_query($sql);
```

The concatenation is incorrect `$sql. =` those should read as `$sql .=` which is why you say that the `DELETE` part works but not the rest following that statement. Had you used `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` it would have signaled the error.

Then you're probably wanting to sanitize input using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) but that's not how that function works and you don't use a `$` sign in front of that function.

It works like this:

```
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['variable']);
```

Read up on the function:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php**

Then you're using `$mysqli_query` with a dollar sign in front of that function, it's just `mysqli_query`.

Then you're doing `SET sStatus = "Human"` that should be single quotes and not double quotes `SET sStatus = 'Human'` and do the same for the other one.

Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and checking for DB error using/adding `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` would have signaled the errors.

Error reporting should have given you warnings such as `Undefined variable...` in regards to `$mysqli_query` and `$mysqli_real_escape_string`.

That should give you enough information to debug your code.

Comment: Downvoter, if you're going to do that and for both answers, do explain. Otherwise, you're not helping. This question dates from yesterday, so this is considered stalking.

Comment: Thank you! After reading through your comments and reading up a bit more I've fixed it and I understand a lot better what I'm doing!

Comment: @tylerkenepp You're very much welcome and I was glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score -1):

Blank page often means syntax error. Maybe it's the one in front of the INSERT statement?

```
$sql. = "INSERT INTO standings ...";
```

Try this one ;)

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO standings ...";
```

Edit: And as mentioned in the comments, it's the first step in debugging. Forgot to say it directly.

Comment: I suggest you go OP's code again and go over it with a *fine toothed comb*, including the comments left under OP's question. You will see I've made a few relevant comments to that effect/affect.

Comment: I believe the original code would serve as a really good interview screening question as I can see at least a half a dozen things *wickedly* wrong at first glance, and there's other things that are worryingly bad. Your fix here is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: It's a good catch, but as Tadman said, it's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: I thought it might help him to find a starting point for debugging. But yeah, overall it's interesting code for an interview screening question. I like that idea @tadman